# How to read a specified sheet from .xlsx file by it's sheet name in alasql

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xlsx, alasql

I, want read a excel file(xls or xlsx), used alasql to read the file.
But I want get a specified sheet(by name). how it will do.

Any good leads is appreciable..

I done some work,

```
alasql('SELECT * FROM FILE(?,{sheetid:"Sheet1"})',[event],function(data){
              console.log(data); });
```

Here "event" is the onload parameter.

Working code but not specified file..

```
alasql('SELECT * FROM FILE(?,{headers:true})',[event],function(data){
          console.log(data); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [read-from-xlsx](https://github.com/agershun/alasql/wiki/XLSX#read-from-xlsx).

Make sure you include the following resources:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alasql/0.4.11/alasql.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.14.2/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.14.2/xlsx.min.js"></script>
```

Then you can access xlsx like this:

```
alasql.promise('select * from xlsx("file.xlsx",{sheetid:"Sheetname"})')
.then(function(data){
  console.log(data);
}).catch(function(err){
  console.log('Error:', err);
});
```